# Reset useState limit request in useEffect (reset to initial limit on value change)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am new to ReactJS and I would like to ask how you can reset a useState when it reaches a specific condition.

In my code I basically have a dropdown selection that returns data based on its selected value.

I can display this with no problem, and was also able to add a 'load more' button to update the limit to request from the API.

My problem now is I want to reset it back to the limit of 10 as I change my dropdown value to something else.

My dropdown code looks like this

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { BreedProvider } from './BreedContext';
import { BreedsContext } from './BreedsContext';
import Cats from './Cats';

const BreedSelection = () => {
  const [breeds] = useContext(BreedsContext);
  const [cat, setCat] = useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setCat(e.target.value);
    setLimit(limit);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="breed">Breed</label>
            <select className="form-control" onChange={handleChange} disabled={breeds.length === 0}>
              <option value={null}>Select Breed</option>
              {breeds.map(breed => (
                <option key={breed.id} value={breed.id}>{breed.name}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <BreedProvider breed={cat} limit={limit}>
        <Cats />
      </BreedProvider>
    </>

  );
}

export default BreedSelection;
```

After which, this then calls my context to display the results and allow the user to load more via a button

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from '../services/axios';
import requests from '../services/requests';

export const BreedContext = createContext();

export const BreedProvider = ({ children, breed, limit }) => {
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(limit);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (breed.length !== 0) {
        const request = await axios.get(requests.fetchBreed + 'page=1&limit=' + showMore + '&breed_id=' + breed);
        setBreeds(request.data);
        console.log('async', request.data.length);
        return request;
      }
    }
    fetchData();

  }, [breed, showMore]);

  return (
    <BreedContext.Provider value={[breeds, setBreeds]}>
      {children}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => { setShowMore(showMore + limit) }}>Load more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BreedContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My problem here now is how do you reset the limit to 10 after you change your dropdown values? ReactJS is very new to me and I just learned this about 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello I did the edit below to reset show More when breed is changed

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from '../services/axios';
import requests from '../services/requests';

export const BreedContext = createContext();

export const BreedProvider = ({ children, breed, limit,resetLimit}) => {
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(limit);
  useEffect(() => {
     if (breed.length !== 0) {
        setShowMore(limit);
     }
  }, [breed]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (breed.length !== 0) {
        const request = await axios.get(requests.fetchBreed + 'page=1&limit=' + showMore + '&breed_id=' + breed);
        setBreeds(request.data);
        console.log('async', request.data.length);
        return request;
      }
    }
    fetchData();

  }, [showMore,breed]);

  return (
    <BreedContext.Provider value={[breeds, setBreeds]}>
      {children}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => { setShowMore(showMore + limit) }}>Load more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BreedContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. I already did this and it does not seem to reset the limit to 10. When I switch my dropdown values to something else, the limit is retained to what was already updated. Say the limit has increased to 20, when I switch to a different option in the dropdown form, it still retains 20 as a limit. It should reset to 10 every iteration.

Comment: Hi, I just understand your issue and I did an update. please look at it.

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be a minor bug. Intermittent issue arise when I do a switch after loading more, and the limit retains itself. Then it fixes itself on the next switch from the dropdown. It seems it's not resetting all the time?

UPDATE: It now works! I just prevented it from calling more than the array length supplied from the API response.

Comment: Good for you @ralphcarlo